# Scale any image to max-width/min-width with keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I want to include an image that should scale up to either a `max-width` or a `max-height` without changing the aspect ratio of that image. This should work for any possible image size.

However the version I came up with does not work for small images (which should also be scaled up).

*Side note: I could do that with some javascript but is there any way how I can do that with plain css?*

```html
<body>
  <div class="ImageContainer">
    <!-- Works for large images -->
    <!--<img src="/assets/American-Magic-1200x628.jpg"/>-->

    <!-- Does not work for small images -->
    <img src="/assets/American-Magic-250x131.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
}

.ImageContainer {
  /*
  width: calc(100vw - 32px);
  height: calc(100vh - 32px);

  max-width: calc(100vw - 32px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 32px);
  */

  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;

  background-color: rgb(
    220,
    100,
    100
  ); /* just visualizing the not-wanted region */
}

.ImageContainer img {
  display: block; /* No whitespace below image */
  max-width: calc(100vw - 32px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 32px);
}
```

[image: Edit max-image-fit-for-small-images]

As said before, it works for large images (they automatically "try to be" as large as their pixel size):
[image: large image]

But it does not work for small images:
[image: small image]

Comment: If you always want it stretched out that large why not use min- width and min-height also?

Comment: @MichaelMayo Because almost every time only one condition of min-width and min-height can be met!

I want all possibe image-aspect ratios to be scaled up to either max-width or max-height whichever property comes first.

Comment: **However the version I came up with does not work for small images** Not entirely true what if the screen is even larger than the largest image ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes, you are right the formulation is not perfect. Better version: "... does not work for sufficiently small images".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your imageContainer div full width and height, and then use object-fit: contain on your image. This will make the image fill the containing element whilst maintaining the aspect ratio.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

[Codesandbox...](https://codesandbox.io/s/max-image-fit-for-small-images-3j059?file=/index.css)

```
.ImageContainer {
  width: calc(100vw - 32px);
  height: calc(100vh - 32px);

  /*
  max-width: calc(100vw - 32px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 32px);
  */

  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;

  background-color: rgb(
    220,
    100,
    100
  ); /* just visualizing the not-wanted region */
}

.ImageContainer img {
  /* display: block; No whitespace below image */
  /* max-width: calc(100vw - 32px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 32px); */

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way how I could make the `.ImageContainer` div also do that so I can keep the rounded corners? Or can I do rounded corners on an `<img>` without a wrapping component?

Comment: @MoritzMakowski Good question, you should be able to put a border-radius directly on an image these days (I think) but I could not get it to work in my example. Sorry, I don't know the answer right now.